# How can I get it so at the top of my search results page it says the amount of results found?

Tags: php, html, search

I have a results page and I would like there to be a bit at the top of the page where it says how many results were returned. How do I do this?

My code is

```
<?php
if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0) {

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

mysql_connect ("3", "", "");
mysql_select_db ("");
if (!empty($_POST["search_string"])) 
{ 

}  

$query = "SELECT name,location,msg FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
location      LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) { ?>
<center>
<table height="20" width="968" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>

<table height="20" width="223" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="helvetica" size="2" color="#045FB4"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></font>
<hr size="1" color="#e6e6e6" width="100%"></hr>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
<td>

<table height="20" width="745" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="helvetica" size="2" color="black"><?php echo $row[1]; ?>
<?php echo $row[2];     ?></font>
<hr size="1" color="#e6e6e6" width="100%"></hr>
<td align="right">
<font face="helvetica" size="2" color="red">See More...</font>
<hr size="1" color="#e6e6e6" width="100%"></hr>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
}
}
?>
</center>
```

THANKS!

James

Comment: Once again, I don't get why is this question so downvoted. It's a beginner question, not a bad question.

Comment: @cypher: it might be because of the terrible HTML and poor PHP practices.  Still, those should only be noted in the answer.  The question is still valid.  I upvoted to help cancel out the downvotes.

Comment: Drive-by downvotes. Apparently they're too cowardly to leave a comment.

Comment: Hi guys, I wondered I what all this is about my html I hear it alot and Ive only really been doing it for some fun for a few months. How else should I be doing it?

Comment: @James: you shouldn't use the font tag and you should be using CSS for formatting.

Comment: Oh ok, why is it better to use css when its just as easy to do what I want with HTML? Are there any other problems with my HTML?

Comment: I hear that a lot: "if it works (and it's easy) why not do it?" Answer: it's harder to maintain. Wanna change the font? Now you have to go through _every_ font tag on _every_ page. With CSS, you make _one_ change in _one_ file.

Comment: @Herbert: I would triple up-vote that answer if I could..

Comment: Table-based layouts are also frowned upon. `center` and `font` are deprecated and you may want to google "SQL Injection Attack". @ClarkeyBoy: it's the thought that counts. :)

Comment: @Herbert: in this case, table is probably okay because he is displaying tabular data.

Comment: Also seconded. Tables should be used only to display data (that's what they were designed for); they make a site easier to understand for users of screen-readers if you use them in the correct structure - for example using a thead for the header-row, th tags for header cells, a tbody to encapsulate all body rows and a tfoot for the footer. th tags can be used both for column headers and row headers. Instead of the outer table try using `<div style='width: 968px; margin: 0 auto;'>...</div>` (I know there is inline styling there; I'm too lazy to write the CSS for it here).

Comment: True. He is displaying tabular data. OTOH, if he's using `font` then there's a good chance he may also be using tables for layout. :) @ClarkeyBoy: nice pointing out screen readers.

Comment: I work for a company which produces AA compliant sites; I've had a fair amount of practice with using them (a lot slower than users who use them on a daily basis though). The markup could also be shortened a fair amount just by combining the two 'inner' tables. I notice the width of both tables adds up to the width of the outer table, so I assume they display side-by-side. You could just put the content of the row in both tables (i.e. the td) into one row in one table, and set the width on the cells instead. Not meaning to seem too critical, just giving advice based on my experience.

Comment: Basically, if you're doing it for fun, do what you like. If you want to go the distance, here's some useful things to look for: `semantic markup`, `separation of content, presentation, and behavior`, `php pdo`, `progressive enhancement`, and about 1000 other things I'm overlooking.I don't think anyone who's commented so far is trying to be judgmental. You're among professionals and some things pop out at us like a sore thumb. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I’m not trying to compete with the other fine answers.** I’m posting this as an answer because it’s too big for a comment.

Since you asked in a comment what could be done to improve your HTML, I refactored your code a bit just to illustrate some things you *could* do. I also included `mysql_num_rows($result)` mentioned by the others for the sake of completion.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Sample</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: small;
    width: 968px;
}
td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.name {
    color:#045FB4;
}
.msg {
    color:black;
}
.more {
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php

if(strlen(trim($_POST['search'])) > 0):

$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search"]);
$searchterm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["searchterm"]);

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("sample");
if (!empty($_POST["search_string"])) 
{
    $search_string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["search_string"]);
    // more code here
}  



$query = "SELECT name,location,msg FROM contact
          WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'
          AND location LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query ($query);
if ($result):

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<p>Found <?php echo $num_rows; ?> results.</p>

<table>
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)):
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td class="msg"><?php echo $row['location'], ' ', $row['msg']; ?></td>
        <td class="more">See More...</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
endif;
?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Normally, I would put the CSS in a separate file, but this is only an example.
Some things to notice:

- There’s only one table
- There’s no style information in the HTML
- It uses `mysql_real_escape_string`. Ideally you'd also want to use **prepared statements**, but I’ll leave that as a personal exercise for you. :)

Even this can be improved quite a bit, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to keep it to one page then [mysql_num_rows](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)() will do the trick and you're good to go. If you use pagination on the other hand, then your SELECT query will have a LIMIT clause and a second query can be constructed using COUNT(*) on the same tables with the same WHERE clause.

```
$total_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND 
                location LIKE '%$searchterm%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mysql_num_rows($query)`. I am no PHP expert but, from memory, that should do the trick. Just echo this wherever you want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name,location,msg FROM contact WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' AND location LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result)
{
    $rs_count = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS();");
    $counted = (int)mysql_result($rs_count, 0);
}
```